# Adding labels and changing x-axis scale in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Thanks to help from this forum, I managed to plot a mean line and a quintile line using `ggplot2`.

```
DF<-data.frame(DOB = c(1965, 1 949, 1964, 1979, 1960, 1992, 1991, 1963, 1964, 1992, 1971, 1965),
               trip.duration.hr =c(3.36, 2.25, 5.31, 10.7, 1.96, 4.33, 23.55, 3.92, 5.46, 3.45, 13.72, 7.33))
```

I have inserted my code below. What I would like to be able to do is

1. Add a label to the mean and quintile lines within the plot area.
2. It currently breaks up the x-axis scale as 20-year intervals. So
   1940, 1960 etc. Can I have it be a narrower scale so every 5 years
   is a separate labeled point on the x-axis?

```
    ggplot(DF, aes(x=DOB, y=trip.duration.hr)) +
      geom_jitter(alpha=1/10) +
      geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun.y = "mean", color="orange", size=1) +
      geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun.y = "quantile", fun.args = list(probs = .9), linetype=2, color="red")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your question 1), one possible solution is to add text label using `geom_text_repel` from `ggrepel` package. However, you will have to decide where you want to place it (here I choose 1965).

For your question 2), you can simply add `breaks` into `scale_x_continuous`.

Altogether, you can do:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

ggplot(DF, aes(x=DOB, y=trip.duration.hr)) +
  geom_jitter(alpha=1/10) +
  geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun = "mean", color="orange", size=1) +
  geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun = "quantile", fun.args = list(probs = .9), linetype=2, color="red")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1950,1995, by = 5))+
  geom_text_repel(data = subset(aggregate(trip.duration.hr ~ DOB, DF, mean), DOB == 1965),
                  label = "Mean", color = "orange", nudge_x = 5, nudge_y = 1)+
  geom_text_repel(data = subset(aggregate(trip.duration.hr ~ DOB, DF, "quantile", probs = 0.9), DOB == 1965),
                  label = "quantile", color = "red", nudge_x = -5, nudge_y = 1)
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?